# Can I have a type safe map that either contains A or List<A>?

Tags: java, generics

I need a Map container that contains either an

> `Item Object`

or

> `List<Item> Object`

as its value, and I can get it out without casting, is it possible?

Comment: The "get it out without casting" part makes me crazy. How are you expecting to use that map? Something like `A a = map.get("key1"); List<A> list = map.get("key2");` can never be possible, because the `get` method can not have two different return types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

[Union types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29) don't exist in Java.  The closest thing you could do in order to get compile-time type checking would be to create list of some custom wrapper class which contained *either* an `A` or a `List<A>`, something like the following:

```
public class UnionListWrapper<A> {
    private final A item;
    private final List<A> list;

    public UnionListWrapper(A value) {
        item = value;
        list = null;
    }

    public UnionListWrapper(List<A> value) {
        item = null;
        list = value;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        if (item != null) return item;
        else return list;
    }
}
```

At least you wouldn't be able to *create* instances of this class that weren't either an `A` or a `List<A>`, but getting the value back out would still have to just be `Object`, with associated casting.  This could get quite clumsy, and on the whole it's probably not worth it.

In practice I'd probably just have a `List<Object>` with some comments around being very careful about what data types are accepted.  The problem is that even run-time checks (sub-optimal) aren't going to be possible, since Java's generic erasure means that you can't do an `instanceof A` check at runtime (doubly so on the generic parameter of the `List`).

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do this in a type-safe manner.

From a design standpoint, I'd suggest using only `List<Item>` as values. If some of them are single-element lists, that's just fine; your code is likely to be much cleaner if you handle all values in the same way.

In fact, I'm curious how you plan to use a map with elements and lists of elements. Do you know which type to expect for a given key a priori?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a MultiMap -- There is an [Apache implementation](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) and a [Google implementation](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: How would a multimap deal with the type-safety issues around different types of values? It seems that both of these implementations require down-casting of `Object` values.

Comment: @erickson -- Well, the Google ones at least are parameterized by key and value types and type safe.

Comment: True, but what can you specify for the parameter? You'd still have `Multimap<Key, Object>` to accommodate `Item` and `List<Item>` as values, so the problem is not changed. I see nothing in the problem statement supports the idea that for a given key, *both* an `Item` and a `List<Item>` will be stored.

Comment: @erickson No, **you** don't store a List<Item>, the multimap does that for you under the covers; you only parameterize by key type and value type.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the type safe heterogeneous container pattern is what you are looking for

http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=type+safe+heterogeneous+container+pattern&source=bl&ots=yYDfNltZS3&sig=giH1d_rIQ-MumOnrMmiT4OgtM7E&hl=en&ei=880dTqHcJYSyhAeVhqS3Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=type%20safe%20heterogeneous%20container%20pattern&f=false

Addressing the good point raised in the comment below re type erasure - using super type tokens. Taken from http://gafter.blogspot.com/2007/05/limitation-of-super-type-tokens.html, which highlights an issue with the approach.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public abstract class TypeRef<T> {
    private final Type type;
    protected TypeRef() {
        ParameterizedType superclass = (ParameterizedType)
            getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        type = superclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
    @Override public boolean equals (Object o) {
        return o instanceof TypeRef &&
            ((TypeRef)o).type.equals(type);
    }
    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return type.hashCode();
    }
}

public class Favorites2 {
    private Map<TypeRef<?>, Object> favorites =
        new HashMap< TypeRef<?> , Object>();
    public <T> void setFavorite(TypeRef<T> type, T thing) {
        favorites.put(type, thing);
    }
    @SuppressWarning("unchecked")
    public <T> T getFavorite(TypeRef<T> type) {
        return (T) favorites.get(type);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Favorites2 f = new Favorites2();
        List<String> stooges = Arrays.asList(
            "Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
        f.setFavorite(new TypeRef<List<String>>(){}, stooges);
        List<String> ls = f.getFavorite(
            new TypeRef<List<String>>(){});
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you get a `Class` instance for the (erased) type `Class<List<Item>>` to use as a key? Also, the type-safe heterogenous container permits only one value per type.

Comment: You can work round type erasure using super type tokens http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html . If there is a requirement to store multiple values of the same type you should be able to meet this requirement by wrapping up heterogenous maps

Comment: Super-type tokens aren't really type-safe though: http://gafter.blogspot.com/2007/05/limitation-of-super-type-tokens.html

Answer (score 0):

Not without writing a wrapper class (WrapsA) which holds either a single A or a List, and making your list be List

Answer (score 0):

[Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/) provides a disjoint union data type called [`Either<A, B>`](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/Either.html), so you can define a `Map<Key, Either<Item, List<Item>>>`.