# Typesafe map-reduce in Java

Tags: java, collections, mapreduce

How to write a type-safe mapper/transformer of collections?

```
class Bean {
 public int value;
}

List<Bean> beans = ..

List<Integer> ints = Lib.map(beans, b => b.value);
```

Using Apache Commons-Collections it looks like this:

```
    Collection<Integer> ints = CollectionUtils.collect(beans, new Transformer() {
        @Override
        public Object transform(Object input) {
            return null; //cast here, dereference etc.
        }
    });
```

But this isn't type safe

Comment: You should go here



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682545/can-i-have-a-type-safe-map-that-either-contains-a-or-lista

Comment: Your code could almost compile as is with Java 8.

Comment: I'd rather stick with a ready-to-use library

Comment: @assylias I know ;) I am using Java 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check guava's `Lists` class out:

```
public static <F,T> List<T> transform(List<F> fromList,
                  Function<? super F,? extends T> function)
```

[API docs here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29)

Comment: Great, way better than Apache!

Comment: @Kent You can fix URLs with parenthesis by URI encoding them as I did in my edit (i.e. replace with `%28` and `%29`), or if the parens are balanced, you can use this syntax: `[link text](http://www.example.com/foo(bar))`

Comment: @gustafc thx, I tried the  latter option in your comment, it didn't work. but i didn't try the first. thanks!

Comment: @Kent yeah, it didn't like the space character either (which actually isn't allowed in URLs and can escaped with `%20`)